# How to load Symfony2 fixtures from migration class?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.4, doctrine-migrations

We've built up a set of data fixtures to seed the database with all our reference values.  We are also using the [DoctrineMigrationsBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/) to manage schema updates.  We would like to trigger the fixture load within our initial schema migration class so the system gets populated before running any additional schema updates.

I found in the docs that you can make [migration classes container aware](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html#container-aware-migrations), but I can't figure out how to jump from that to calling/running the data fixtures.  I haven't found any good answers on Stackoverflow or via google.  Has anyone done this and can point me in the right direction? (or have suggestions on a better way to manage seed data in conjunction with schema migrations).  Thanks.

This is using Symfony Version: 2.4

Answer (score 7):

This is interesting question. I've found the "dirty" solution, but it works well.

```
namespace Application\Migrations;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\AbstractMigration;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;

class Version20140811164659 extends AbstractMigration implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    private $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function up(Schema $schema)
    {
        // ... your code here
    }

    public function postUp(Schema $schema)
    {
        // here you have to define fixtures dir
        $this->loadFixtures('src/Acme/BlogBundle/DataFixtures/ORM');
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema)
    {
        // ... your code here
    }

    public function loadFixtures($dir, $append = true)
    {
        $kernel = $this->container->get('kernel');
        $application = new \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application($kernel);
        $application->setAutoExit(false);

        //Loading Fixtures
        $options = array('command' => 'doctrine:fixtures:load', "--fixtures" => $dir, "--append" => (boolean) $append);
        $application->run(new \Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput($options));
    }
}
```

This solution simply running console command `php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --fixtures=src/Acme/BlogBundle/DataFixtures/ORM --append` after "up" migration.
Sorry for poore English. If you'll find clear solution, share it ;)

Answer (score 2):

I've made a migration class to address this very problem. The code is essentially inspired from the doctrine:fixtures:load command.

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Migrations;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\ORMExecutor;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\ORMPurger;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\AbstractMigration;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\DataFixtures\ContainerAwareLoader;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

abstract class AbstractFixturesAwareMigration extends AbstractMigration implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    private $container;
    private $fixtures;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    protected function getContainer()
    {
        return $this->container;
    }

    protected function addFixture(FixtureInterface $fixture)
    {
        if(null === $this->fixtures) {
            $this->fixtures = new ContainerAwareLoader($this->getContainer());
        }

        $this->fixtures->addFixture($fixture);

        return $this;
    }

    protected function executeFixtures($em = null, $append = true, $purgeMode = ORMPurger::PURGE_MODE_DELETE)
    {
        $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager($em);
        $purger = new ORMPurger($em);
        $purger->setPurgeMode($purgeMode);
        $executor = new ORMExecutor($em, $purger);
        $executor->execute($this->fixtures->getFixtures(), $append);
        $this->fixtures = null;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Usage is pretty straightforward:

```php
<?php

namespace Application\Migrations;

use AppBundle\Migrations\AbstractFixturesAwareMigration
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * Auto-generated Migration: Please modify to your needs!
 */
class Version20170726102103 extends AbstractFixturesAwareMigration
{        
    /**
     * @param Schema $schema
     */
    public function up(Schema $schema)
    {
        // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        // [...]
    }

    public function postUp(Schema $schema)
    {
        // LoadMyData can be any fixture class
        $this->addFixture(new LoadMyData());
        $this->executeFixtures();
    }        

    /**
     * @param Schema $schema
     */
    public function down(Schema $schema)
    {
        // this down() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        // [...]
    }
}
```